# Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGFloat' (aka 'double') and 'UIView * _Nullable')

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode8

Hi i am getting the following error while converting from swift to objective c code. Please see the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try removing the ! after superview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike Taverne commented, the ! needs to go.
Insead of `!.` I think you probably want `->` if the is supposed to be objective C. ObjC seems to think you want to subtract  _profileBelowView.superView from offsetY. You could try putting parentheses around the second half of the subtraction. That's not the real problem here but you might have gotten a better error message once the order of operations issue was removed.